# Abstract class error in java

Tags: java, abstract

I'm trying to figure out why i keep getting the error that my AM class does not override abstract method. In my teachers UML diagram it only shows that i need the equals (Object o) method in my parent radio class. Also i'm not declaring it as abstract in my abstract class.

```
public abstract class Radio implements Comparable
{
 double currentStation;

 RadioSelectionBar radioSelectionBar;
 public Radio()
 {
   this.currentStation = getMin_Station();
 }
 public abstract double getMax_Station();
 public abstract double getMin_Station();
 public abstract double getIncrement();
 public void up()
 {

 }
 public void down()
 {

 }
 public double getCurrentStaion()
 {
   return this.currentStation;
 }
 public void setCurrentStation(double freq)
 {
   this.currentStation = freq;
 }
 public void setStation(int buttonNumber, double station)
 {
 }
 public double getStation(int buttonNumber)
 {
   return 0.0;
 }
 public String toString()
 {
   String message = ("" + currentStation);
   return message;
 } 

 public boolean equals (Object o)    
 {        
   if (o == null)           
     return false;        
   if (! (o instanceof Radio))           
     return false;       
   Radio other = (Radio) o;       
   return this.currentStation == other.currentStation;    
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Radio amRadio = new AMRadio();

   System.out.println(amRadio);

   Radio fmRadio = new FMRadio();

   System.out.println(fmRadio);

   Radio xmRadio = new XMRadio();

   System.out.println(xmRadio);

 }  
}


public class AMRadio extends Radio
{
  private static final double Max_Station = 1605;
  private static final double Min_Station = 535;
  private static final double Increment = 10;
  public AMRadio()
  {
    currentStation = Min_Station;
  }
  public  double getMax_Station()
  {
    return this.Max_Station;
  }
  public  double getMin_Station()
  {
    return this.Min_Station;
  }
  public  double getIncrement()
  {
    return this.Increment;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    String message = ("AM " + this.currentStation);
    return message;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement the [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method, given that `Radio` implements the `Comparable` interface and a concrete implementation for this method wasn't provided in the `Radio` class, so you have two choices:

1. Implement `compareTo()` in all of `Radio`'s subclasses
2. Or implement `compareTo()` in `Radio`

Something like this, in `AMRadio`:

```
public int compareTo(AMRadio o) {
    // return the appropriate value, read the linked documentation
}
```

Or like this, in `Radio`:

```
public int compareTo(Radio o) {
    // return the appropriate value, read the linked documentation
}
```